# How I use a T4 template file in another T4 file

Tags: t4

I have a file with t4 code, but I want to separate it into 2 files, how I do a include tt file in my tt file?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [include directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-include-directive?view=vs-2017) in Microsoft docs